# Stripe checkout embedded form response

Tags: httpresponse, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I am use stripe embedded form for checkout

```
<script  src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
         data-key="{!! env('STRIPE_PK') !!}"
         data-amount="{{$total*100}}"
         data-name="LaravelShop.IO"
         data-description="Products"
         data-image="/128x128.png"
         data-locale="auto">
 </script>
```

My question is how I can display error returned from `https://api.stripe.com/v1/tokens` after clicking `Blue Payment Button`.
Any link or code snippet.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't. If the token creation fails, the [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) form itself will handle the error and the form will not be submitted.

Depending on the reason for the failure, a message will be displayed and certain fields will be highlighted in red.